# Get file count in jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload

I'm using [jQueryFileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to manage images in a folder. I'm trying to get the count of actual uploaded files. Actual means that I would like to increment a variable each time a new (single/multiple) upload is successfully performed and decrement it when files are deleted.

From official documentation, I've found these [callbacks](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options). I've successfully attached a callback to file uploader:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) 
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Unfortunately, this solution has the following problems:

- I'm not able to get the number of actual uploaded files in multiple uploads
- callback is invoked on uploads only (not on delete)

Is there a way to keep the count of uploaded files after each upload/delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a count for successfully uploaded files like below:

```
var filesuploadedSuccess =0;     
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
  filesuploaded ++;
 });
```

Similarly you can use fileuploadfailed event to get failed upload count.

Use fileuploaddestroyed event to get the count for deleted files.

```
 $('#fileupload') .bind('fileuploaddestroyed', function (e, data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it still remains the problem of keeping track of deleted files (which is the biggest problem for me).

Comment: Either there can be a success or fail condition after each upload. When are you getting file deleted?

Comment: After successful uploads, a list of uploaded files is presented to you. Here you can decide to delete one or multiple files. And my goal is to keep track both of successful uploads and successful deletions.

Comment: You can use fileuploaddestroyed event to get the count for deleted files.
$('#fileupload')
    .bind('fileuploaddestroyed', function (e, data)